# Second derivative notation?

Tags: derivatives

The second derivative is defined as d/dx(dy/dx).
I have multiplied so that it is simplified, so the second derivative is, d^2x/(dx)^2, yet in some books it states it as d^2x/d(x)^2.
Can this limit not act as a fraction?

Comment: Are you series?

Comment: @SPARSE, does the question sound sarcastic? It was not meant to be sarcastic. Yes I am the sum of a sequence.

Comment: ...............?